# keep an image static while parent is slide up and down

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

in the example below there is a gold div named `she`
in reality this is an image with same properties
clicking on button I need the `she` to be revealed gradually and not moving with the bottom side of parent
just like `story` - it is fixed and revealed gradually by parent's sliding.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
$('#swtop').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.swtop{
display:none;
background:lightblue;
position:relative;
}
.space{height:34px;}
.story{text-align:center;}
.she{
position:absolute;
left:25px; bottom:0; width:5%;
background:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br><br>
<div class='swtop' id='swtop'>
<div class='space'></div>
<div class='story'>LOREM IPSUM</div>
<div class='space'></div>
<div class='she'><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```

Comment: and you need position:absolute?

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I need that `she` image to be bottom left - probably absolute is a must

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an extra wrapper:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#swtop').slideToggle();
});
```

```css
.swtop {
  display: none;
  background: lightblue;
}

.swtop > div {
  position: relative; /* we move this to the extra wrapper */
}

.space {
  height: 34px;
}

.story {
  text-align: center;
}

.she {
  position: absolute;
  left: 25px;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 5%;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br><br>
<div class='swtop' id='swtop'>
  <div>
    <div class='space'></div>
    <div class='story'>LOREM IPSUM</div>
    <div class='space'></div>
    <div class='she'><br><br><br></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

And it is another way to make it beautiful.

```js
let sts = false;
$('button').on('click', function(){
    sts = !sts;
  if (sts){
        $('#swtop').slideToggle();
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('.she').fadeToggle();
      }, 300);
  }else{
        $('.she').fadeToggle();
      setTimeout(function(){
        $('#swtop').slideToggle();
      }, 300);
  }
});
```

```css
.swtop{
  display:none;
  background:lightblue;
  position:relative;
}
.space{
  height:34px;
  }
.story{
  text-align:center;
  }
.she{
  position:absolute;
  left:25px;
  bottom:0;
  width:5%;
  background:gold;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br><br>
<div class='swtop' id='swtop'>
  <div class='space'></div>
  <div class='story'>LOREM IPSUM</div>
  <div class='space'></div>
  <div class='she'><br><br><br></div>
</div>
```